# How to set the text in sans-serif without using \tcblower?

Tags: fonts, tcolorbox

When defining a `tcolorbox`-environment, there is the option `fontlower` available. However I have yet to discover to invoke that setting without using `\tcbolower`.

Is it possible to get the content in the box set in sans-serif without using `tcblower`?

I would prefer a native solution instead of a) using an unnecessary command, b) that dashed rule/line and/or c) using a work-around to circumvent the production of said rule.

## Screenshot of problematic MWE

[image]

## Problematic MWE

```
\documentclass[
parskip=false
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{specialnote}[1]{
fonttitle=\Large\sffamily,
halign title=center,
sharp corners,
colback=white,
title={#1},
width=(0.85\columnwidth),
center,
enhanced,
frame style={
top color=black!70!white,
bottom color=black!50!green
},
boxrule=2mm,
fontlower=\sffamily,
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\section{Just some words without meaning}
Abc.
Def.

\begin{specialnote}
{Look look!}
\tcblower
asdfasdf
\end{specialnote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, are you looking for `fontupper=\sffamily`?

Comment: @Marijn Oh. Yes. Was not aware that `fontupper` can exist without the "dividing the content up"-part. Thanks! Please post your comment as a reply so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: Also, I attributed the "upper" part to the title/heading of the box somehow. Guess that played into my thinking.

Comment: All `...upper` options are applied to a not divided box (without lower part) or to the upper part of a divided box. There exist independent options for `title`.

Comment: @henry let's close as a duplicate instead.